# Silverlight HttpWebRequest throws a 404 Not Found exception before Webservice responds

Tags: silverlight, httpwebrequest

I'm trying to call a Restful service from a Silverlight 4 Out of browser application using the ClientHttp Stack.

```
var request = (HttpWebRequest)HttpWebRequest.Create(uri);
request.BeginGetResponse(new AsyncCallback(ExecuteResponseCallback), state);
```

The service i'm calling takes upto 20 seconds to respond after receiving the request, but it seems that the callback method is fired after around 10 seconds. I can see in Fiddler that the service does finally complete the request after a total of 30 seconds with a 200 Response code, but the HttpWebRequest callback has already received a 404 Not Found response.

I can't see any reason why this should happen, there is no Timeout property on the HttpWebRequest in Silverlight, so I cannot understand why the request does not wait indefinitely for the response.

Is there something I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a little more testing it turns out the callback is fired at exactly 10 seconds. It turned out to be caused by the registry key

```
HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Internet Settings\ReceiveTimeout
```

Installing IE9 64bit seems to be the culprit, as well as some other applications that modify this value. The solution was simply to delete this registry key and all is well.

The problem is also described here [Silverlight ClientHttp WebRequest timeout](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5475022/silverlight-clienthttp-webrequest-timeout)